# How to download file from hyperlink?

Tags: android, hyperlink, download, textview

In my android app I have to textviews that are hyperlinks and when clicked directly link to a file on my server. When I click on a link that points to an audio file it begins to stream the file so everything with that is working. Now I would like to know if it is possible to directly download a file from a hyperlink and I don't want to code the urls in the actvity because I am parsing the textviews from mysql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I am looking for I want to know if its possible to download files directly from a hyperlink